# temperature class with arrays java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So, I'm supposed to create 3 arrays of random sizes of 1 to 5 elements using the random number generator. I created a method called **getRandomArraySize()** that does that.

```
    import java.util.Random;
    
    public class TemperatureDemoWithArrays
    {
        public static int getRandomArraySize()
        {
            Random randomArray = new Random();
            
            int arraySize = randomArray.nextInt() % 5 + 1;
            
            int[] temperatureArray = new int[arraySize];
            
            for(int i = 0; i < temperatureArray.length; i++)
            {
                temperatureArray[i] = randomArray.nextInt();
            }
            
            return arraySize;
        }


My professor gave us a demo program to use. We're not supposed to alter it at all. Everything is under the main method. 

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x;
        Temperature average;
        
        System.out.println("You will be asked to fill 3 randomly sized arrays.");
        
        Temperature[] temperatureArrayOne;
        Temperature[] temperatureArrayTwo;
        Temperature[] temperatureArrayThree;
        
        temperatureArrayOne = new Temperature[getRandomArraySize()];
        readTemperatureArray(temperatureArrayOne);
        System.out.println("The values of temperature array one are ");
        printTemperatureArray(temperatureArrayOne);
        average = getAverage(temperatureArrayOne);
        System.out.println("The average of temperature array one is " + average);

        temperatureArrayTwo = new Temperature[getRandomArraySize()];
        readTemperatureArray(temperatureArrayTwo);
        System.out.println("The values of temperature array two are ");
        printTemperatureArray(temperatureArrayTwo);
        average = getAverage(temperatureArrayTwo);
        System.out.println("The average of temperature array two is " + average);

        temperatureArrayThree = new Temperature[getRandomArraySize()];
        readTemperatureArray(temperatureArrayThree);
        System.out.println("The values of temperature array three are ");
        printTemperatureArray(temperatureArrayThree);
        average = getAverage(temperatureArrayThree);
        System.out.println("The average of temperature array three is " + average);
```

I'm trying to call the **getRandomArraySize()** with this line of code **Temperature[] temperatureArrayOne = new Temperature[getRandomArraySize()];** I'm getting an error on this line that says **Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int**. I tried putting the **getRandomArraySize()** method inside and outside the main method. I keep getting the same error. Please help!

Comment: getRandomArraySize() is returning an array `int[]`, not `int`.  Given the name of the function, I think it should be returning a number rather than an array of numbers.  Currently it's always returning an array of 5 integers, where the integers are random, and I don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: You're right but I shouldn't know how many numbers it's going to output. That's why it's random. What I do know is that it should output at least one number or maximum 5 numbers. Could you give me some hints or point me in the right direction on how to do is?

Comment: Well instead of `new int[5];` you could initialize it with `new int[arraySize];`, and previously you'd set `arraySize` to random number modulus 5.  A number modulus 5 will give a number from 0 to 4, so you'd add one to it, eg `int arraySize = randomArray.nextInt() % 5 + 1;`

Comment: So, am I still returning temperatureArray because I'm still getting the same error?

Comment: If you disregard my first comment, and do as I suggested in the second, then you'd have a function that returns an array with 1 to 5 entries, all random.  So you're done.  Just print the array in the mainline.

Comment: Wait, I just saw your comment on another answer that you cannot change the mainline.  I think you should edit your code to make that very clear, and post the entire mainline that you are not allowed to change.  I think your `getRandomArraySize` function would become very simple.  Make it return an `int`, and return the variable `arraySize` from my previous comment.

Comment: Ok. I made the changes you said and added the main program my professor wants us to use. So, I have the getRandomArraySize() return arraySize now and I don't get any more errors. Should, I be able to system print it out in the main method to check if I'm getting 5 random numbers?

Comment: OK now that it's clear that you can't change the main method, my very first comment applies :-) .It should return `int`, and not `int[]`.  In other words it simply returns a random number from 1 to 5 as I outlined in another comment.

Comment: Thank u very much. U were very helpful. I found what I was doing wrong and fixed it. Hopefully you're around if I have any other question in the future

Answer (score 0):

From the name of your variable `temperatureArrayOne` I think you should just take the **first** value of your array:

```
Temperature[] temperatureArrayOne = new Temperature[getRandomArraySize()[0]];
```

Comment: I'm not supposed to alter that part because it's part of the demo program my professor gave us to use. I actually changed it in the getRandomArraySize() method. I changed return temperatureArray; to return temperatureArray[0]; and the error went away. Now, I'm getting another error. I tried printing out temperatureArray in the main method to see if at least it gave me one number and it says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at TemperatureDemoWithArrays.main

Answer (score 0):

In a verbose manner you can do as next:

```
 int[] sizesArray = TemperatureDemoWithArrays.getRandomArraySize();
 int size = sizesArray[0];
 Temperature[] instances = new Temperature[size];
```

Which can be written also as next:

```
 int[] size = TemperatureDemoWithArrays.getRandomArraySize()[0];
 Temperature[] instances = new Temperature[size];
```

Or also as next:

```
Temperature[] instances = new Temperature[TemperatureDemoWithArrays.getRandomArraySize()[0]];
```

Notices that for the above example, the **0** index is used all the time to obtain the size. You may use from 0 to 4 as you have defined a 5 entries array.